# how do i create a computational expression that takes parameters?

Tags: f#, monads

I want to create a couple of computational expressions that would be used to access the database and return a list of items like so (I also have questions in the code comments):

```
let foo x y z = proc "foo" {
    let! cmd = proc.CreateCommand() // can I do this?
    do! In "x" DbType.Int32 // would i gain anything by replacing DbType with a union 
                            // type since the names would match actual data types?
    do! In "y" DbType.String 15;
    cmd?x <- x
    cmd?y <- y
    use! r = cmd.ExecuteReader() // would this be bad form for creating a workflow builder?
    return! r {
        let item = MyItem()
        do! item.a <- r.GetInt32("a")
        do! item.a <- r.GetString("b")
        do! item.c <- r.GetDateTime("c")
        yield! item
    }
}
```

How can I create a workflow builder such that an instance of it takes a parameter?

```
let proc name = ProcedureBuilder(connStr, factory) // how do I do this?
```

Comment: have you seen FsSql? https://github.com/mausch/FsSql or Ademar's sql comp.expr? http://ademar.name/blog/2010/10/a-recipe-for-typed-sql-databas.html http://ademar.name/blog/2010/10/typed-sql-access-second-take.html

Comment: I have not, I will take a look at it. thanks

Comment: @Daniel ;-) @kvb has a great answer already, so I could take a break. Although I wrote code that uses this recently, so I'll share it here.

Comment: Cool!  I never even thought about trying this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  You can use computation expression syntax after any expression with a type statically known to expose the right methods.  So the following code works (but doesn't do anything particularly interesting):

```
let f x = async
let v = f "test" { return 1 }
```

Here, `f` has type `'a -> AsyncBuilder`, so `f "test"` has type `AsyncBuilder` and can be followed with computation expression syntax.  Your example of `let proc name = ProcedureBuilder(connStr, factory)` is perfectly fine, assuming that `ProcedureBuilder` is defined appropriately, though you presumably want `name` to appear somewhere in the constructor arguments.

Comment: this whole currying thing still catches me off guard. Thanks for the excellent explanation. To make sure I fully understand. since I have parameters for <code>proc</code> as opposed to <code>let proc = ProcedureBuilder()<code> the Procedure builder doesn't get executed until I call the function, where without the parameter the code gets executed and bound to proc imediately. The former gets a new instance every time and the latter is the same instance over and over. Correct?

Answer (score 4):

The answer from Keith (kvb) is correct - you can use parameterized computation builders. The syntax of computation expressions is:

```
<expr> { <cexpr> }
```

So, the builder can be created by any expression. Usually, it is some value (e.g. `async`) but it can be a function call or even a constructor call. When using this, you would typically define a parameterized builder and then pass the argument to a constructor using a function (as @kvb suggests).

I actually wrote an example of this, not a long time ago, so I can share an example where - I think - this is quite useful. You can find it on F# snippets: http://fssnip.net/4z

The example creates a "special" asynchronous computation builder for ASP.NET MVC that behaves just like standard `async`. The only difference is that it adds `Run` member that uses `AsyncManager` (provided by ASP.NET) to execute the workflow.

Here are some relevant parts from the snippet:

```
/// A computation builder that is almost the same as stnadard F# 'async'.
/// The differnece is that it takes an ASP.NET MVC 'AsyncManager' as an
/// argumnet and implements 'Run' opration, so that the workflow is 
/// automatically executed after it is created (using the AsyncManager)
type AsyncActionBuilder(asyncMgr:Async.AsyncManager) = 
  // (Omitted: Lots of boilerplate code)

  /// Run the workflow automatically using ASP.NET AsyncManager
  member x.Run(workflow) = 
    // Use 'asyncMgr' to execute the 'workflow'
```

The snippet wraps the construction in a base class, but you could define a function:

```
let asyncAction mgr = new AsyncActionBuilder(mgr)
```

And then use it to define asynchronous action in ASP.NET MVC:

```
member x.LengthAsync(url:string) = asyncAction x.AsyncManager {
    let wc = new WebClient()
    let! html = wc.AsyncDownloadString(url)
    return html.Length }
```